# Sobreescribir !important css

Tags: css

Tengo un div que tiene `!important` pero necesito darle mas importancia a otro en un determinado caso.

¿Hay alguna regla para darle mas importancia al otro div que tiene `!important`?

Comment: Javier, bienvenido, podrias agregar el código html y css? De modo que la respuesta pueda ser orientada a tu caso en particular.

Comment: ¿Quieres decir `!important`?

Comment: La **[doc dice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad#La_excepción_!important)** que `!important` es **una excepción** y que su uso es una mala práctica: _Cuando se emplea important en una declaración de estilo, esta declaración sobrescribe a cualquier otra. **El uso de !important, es una mala práctica y debería evitarse porque hace que el código sea más difícil de depurar porque rompre la cascada natural de las hojas de estilo.** Cuando dos declaraciones en conflicto con el !important son aplicadas al mismo elemento, se aplicará la declaración con mayor especificidad._

Comment: Si hay, pero por favor agrega tu HTML y CSS así te podemos ayudar

Comment: abajo te sugieren JQuery, aunque la respuesta tiene varios negativos, supongo que si no te importa jugar con JQuery es lo optimo

Answer (score 13):

## Opción 1: Evita el uso de `!important`en la medida de lo posible

La [doc dice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad#La_excepci%C3%B3n_!important) que `!important` es una excepción y que su uso es una mala práctica.

Es posible establecer prioridades, sin tener que usar `!important`.  A no ser que por algún motivo tengas que usarlo obligatoriamente. Si tal es el caso, puedes ver la **opción 2** de esta respuesta.

Si quieres darle prioridad a un elemento sobre otro, puedes darle una etiqueta o identificador de carácter superior, que tenga más prioridad. Si quieres más detalles sobre esta práctica, que es la recomendada por Mozilla Developer Network, consulta lo explicado en la [especificación de CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad).

Veamos:

### Ejemplo 1, que se podría aplicar a tu caso:

En este ejemplo, tendrán prioridad los `div` con id (`prioritario-a` y `prioritario-b`), sobre los divs con nombres de clases (`test-a` y `test-b`). Verás que aunque la regla CSS relativa a la clase aparece de último en la cascada, prevalece la regla relativa al id, porque el id tiene prioridad sobre la clase.

Esta es una buena práctica para aplicar prioridades, evitando el uso de `!important`.

```css
#prioritario-a,
#prioritario-b {
  color: red;
}

.test-a {
  color: blue;
}

.test-b {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-a" id="prioritario-a">Texto1 prioritario en rojo</div>
<div class="test-a">Texto1 no prioritario</div>
<div class="test-b" id="prioritario-b">Texto2 prioritario en rojo</div>
<div class="test-b">Texto2 no prioritario</div>
```

El ejemplo aplica lo que dice la documentación:

> En lugar de usar `!important`, considera:
>
> Hacer un mejor uso de las propiedades en cascada de CSS. Usar reglas
>   más específicas. Indicando uno o más elementos antes del elemento que
>   estás seleccionando, la regla se vuelve más específica y gana mayor
>   prioridad.

Ver también: [Reviewing CSS Style Priority Level](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/) sobre la prioridad de los elementos.

Y recomiendo leer este artículo (en inglés), el cual da varios motivos contundentes para evitar `!important`: [CSS !important Rule: How to Use It Correctly](https://appendto.com/2016/04/css-important-rule-how-to-use-it-correctly/)

### ¿Por qué `!important` es una mala práctica?

> Cuando se emplea important en una declaración de estilo, esta
>   declaración sobrescribe a cualquier otra. **El uso de `!important`, es una
>   mala práctica y debería evitarse porque hace que el código sea más
>   difícil de depurar porque rompre la cascada natural de las hojas de
>   estilo**. Cuando dos declaraciones en conflicto con el `!important` son
>   aplicadas al mismo elemento, se aplicará la declaración con mayor
>   especificidad.

Según la documentación (enlace citado más arriba) `!important` debe usarse solamente cuando no haya otra alternartiva. Es decir, en dos casos concretos:

> - Tienes un archivo CSS que establece aspectos visuales de tu sitio de manera global.
> - Tú (u otros) usas estilos inline en los propios elementos. Esto es considerado como una muy mala práctica. En este caso, puede establecer
>     ciertos estilos en su archivo CSS global como importantes, superando
>     así los estilos en línea configurados directamente en los elementos.

---

### Opción 2: Estoy obligado por cualquier motivo a usar `!important`

Si no tienes escapatoria y estás obligado a usar `!important`, la doc también explica la mejor forma de sobre-escribirlo:

> #### Cómo sobrescribir !important
>
> **A)** Simplemente añade otra regla CSS con `!important` y, o bien da al
>   selector una especificidad mayor (añadiendo una etiqueta, id o clase
>   al selector), o añadiendo una regla CSS con el mismo selector en un
>   punto posterior al ya existente. Esto funciona porque en caso de
>   empate en especificidad, la última regla prevalece.
>
> Algunos ejemplos con una gran especificidad:
>
> ```
> table td    {height: 50px !important;}
> .myTable td {height: 50px !important;}
> #myTable td {height: 50px !important;}
> ```
>
> **B)** O añade el mismo selector después de uno existente:
>
> ```
>  td {height: 50px !important;}
> ```
>
> **C)** O reescribe la regla original para evitar el uso de `!important.`

#### `Ejemplo 2, sobre-escribiendo !important:`

```css
/* Forma A*/

#prioritario-a {
  color: red !important;
}

div p {
  color: green !important;
}

.test p {
  color: blue !important;
}


/* Forma B*/

#prioritario-b {
  color: blue !important;
}

#prioritario-b {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Forma A según la doc-->


<div class="test">
  <p>Texto A</p>
  <p id="prioritario-a">Texto A prioritario en rojo</p>
</div>

<!-- Forma B según la doc-->


<div class="test">
  <p>Texto B</p>
  <p id="prioritario-b">Texto B prioritario en rojo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, lamento que te hallan dado calificaciones negativas sin razón alguna

Comment: A veces ocurre eso en SO, @DiegoVallejo. Algunos se esconden tras los votos negativos y ni siquiera comentan el motivo de dicho voto. De todos modos, con el tiempo, las respuestas se van valorando y se irá votando según se consideren buenas o no. Lo malo es cuando se vota en contra para quitar mérito o para hacer favorecer otra respuesta que puede no ser la más idónea. Es como en la vida, hay de todo.

Comment: Lo único que no me gustó es que utiliza el mismo ID en varios elementos, el cuál W3C especifica que el comportamiento de document.getElementByID es indefinido, cualquier cosa podría pasar, igual voto positivo.

Comment: Lo sé @EduenSarceño . Lo he hecho así para simplificar el ejemplo ya que la idea era mostrar que el `id`  tiene prioridad sobre `class`. Evidentemente, si tuviera que recuperar el valor del elemento por JS no habría colocado el mismo `id`. Valga la aclaración en tu comentario, pondré una nota en el código.

Comment: Es evidente que no te has tomado el tiempo de leer la respuesta @NetVicious Te muestra cómo ir a Madrid, por **dos caminos**, el mejor y el más corto, y el más largo, si por algún motivo estás obligado a ello. Si tomas el más largo, serás consciente de que lo es. Y te da el mapa para llegar por cualquiera de los dos. Sugiero que leas bien la respuesta, que pruebes el código (el botón azul, ya sabes) y luego comentes. Estoy seguro que en este caso los votos negativos han sido dados por otros motivos distintos al que argumentas.

Comment: Cierto, no la lei entera. Y creo que el que metió el -1 tampoco.

Comment: Los que metieron el -1, lo hicieron cuando vieron que era yo el autor de la respuesta. No tenía ni un minuto de haberla publicado y ya tenía dos puntos negativos. ¡Un tiempo record! @NetVicious

Comment: Gran respuesta. Aumento los votos positivos ;)

Comment: Yo soy el autor de 1 de los 3 votos negativos que tiene esta respuesta: Al momento de publicarla, la respuesta no resolvía el problema ni respondía a la pregunta planteada. ¿por qué mantengo el voto negativo? Porque el problema solo se resuelve al final de la misma, después de un largo recorrido por explicaciones y enlaces. En mi opinión se debe solucionar primero el problema actual y luego sí explicar las buenas prácticas y etc. ¿por qué? Porque no necesariamente el OP o quienes entren tienen el tiempo o el conocimiendo para leer y entender todos los detalles técnicos y opciones posibles.

Comment: Creía que había revisado las ediciones, pensaba que la respuesta estaba completa al principio pero tienes razón @Shaz. Tal y como esta ahora aunque da muchas vueltas antes de llegar a la solución yo no votaría negativo pero es solo mi opinión, si los votos no son nada personal todo bien. Creo que estas discusiones están generando demasiado ruido y me incluyo (por eso borro mi comentario anterior), procuraré tratar estos temas en _meta_.

Comment: @Shaz no sé si sabes que eres el usuario de SO que otorga más votos negativos, mucho más de la mitad con diferencia de los votos positivos que otorgas: [Mayores votadores en contra](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/691667/top-downvoters). Me consta que en ocasiones tus votos en contra son por cuestiones personales. Pero como se ha dicho, es un tema para debatir en Meta. Lo bueno es que los votos negativos te ayudan a mejorar tu respuesta, a superarte. Considero que ni al principio, ni ahora, el voto negativo es justificado, pero cada uno es libre de hacer lo que quiera.

Comment: @A.Cedano sí, desde antes que ingresaras a SOes he sido la persona que más votos negativos ha emitido. Si te consta que varios de mis votos en contra son personales, te invito a demostrarlo (en Meta).

Comment: Ya he comentado varias veces en Meta que mi labor principal no es la informática, @Shaz . Es decir, dedico un tiempo a tratar de ayudar y no quiero perder mi tiempo en asuntos como estos. Existen comentarios tuyos con ofensas personales hacia mi persona y mi condición. Tú tienes una conciencia, y es ahí donde debe ser demostrada la intención de tus actos. Al menos, cuando votes en contra, deja un comentario, lo cual equivale a dar la cara, a ser responsable de sus actos. Lamento tener que comentar esto aquí, lo cual se hace desagradable para mi.

Comment: @A.Cedano Bueno, te invito a llevar el tema personal a Meta, utilizando "nombres propios" y por cierto, mi pregunta fue si te constaba de alguna forma que mis votos negativos fueran personales, nunca hablé de comentarios. ¡Buen día!

Comment: Me consta @Shaz, y no sólo a mi, sino a otros usuarios de amplia reputación en SO. Ante situaciones así, demostrar no sirve de nada, por eso he apelado a tu conciencia porque aunque votes en contra  y eso pueda molestarme, el más afectado eres tú. A veces es saludable ver el lado positivo de la vida... revisar algunas respuestas que sean buenas y votarlas a favor. Nadie te ha dado la misión de ser el gruñón se SO. Que pases un excelente día. Por mi parte, no hay nada contra ti. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente respuesta @A.Cedano , es una lástima no tengas más votos positivos en esta respuesta que puede ayudar a muchos a trabajar mejor con las hojas de estilos.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. la respuesta tiene en este momento `8` votos a favor, y `3` en contra, por eso aparece un total de `5` votos. Cuando se escribió la respuesta eran momentos tensos en SO por motivos que ignoro. Eso ha cambiado para bien de todos. De todo se aprende, con lo ocurrido aprendes a aceptar que no todos piensen como tú. Si en el pasado hubo momentos tensos con ciertos usuarios, eso se convirtió en colaboración amable en futuras respuestas en las que nos vimos implicados. También los votos negativos son una ayuda y un desafío para que mejores la respuesta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Debes especificar un selector mas directo o especifico sobre el elemento para poder sobre escribirlo:

```css
span{
  color: yellow !important;
}

div section span{
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <section>
      <span>
        hola mundo
      </span>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: El uso de `!important` es **una mala práctica** porque **rompe** la cascada. Hay otras formas de hacerlo, como explico en mi respuesta.

Comment: La pregunta no es si es mala practica o no. Es sobre como sobre escribir el css del elemento.

Comment: Mi ejemplo muestra una forma de sobrescribirlo, usando una buena práctica, como podrás ver. Te invito a leer la respuesta completa y a retirar el voto negativo ya que el código funciona y además aplica una buena practica, recomendada por la documentación.

Comment: Imagina que el/ella este utilizando bootstrap y uno de los estilos tenga `!important`. Como puede tu respuesta ayudarlo? O pretentes que edite todos los estilos y borre todas las reglas que tengan `!important`?

Comment: Aunque tenga bootstrap o lo que tenga, el código funcionará y al mismo tiempo no promoverá un estilo de programación poco recomendado. ¡Usar important por todas partes, eso es algo pésimo!

Comment: Aún si es una pésima práctica, hay proyectos en los que TIENES que sobreescribirlos y encontrar la forma de lidiar con ellos, bien sea porque el proyecto fue creado con dependencias que no se DEBEN modificar, o porque no se puede tocar el código existente (por el motivo que sea), en muchas ocasiones simplemente hay que resolver el problema sin poder "atacar" la causa. La solución de @Einer es válida en este caso.