# Contadores HTML con estilo

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de hacer como una lista de cosas ordenadas (Con bastante texto en cada una).

Como la típica lista  me parecía muy sosa, busqué por la web y encontré [este resultado](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp) que me gustó. Entonces busqué el código, pero no encontré nada.

Así que intentando hacerlo igual, me quedé atascada y sin saber muy bien cómo seguir. Tengo esto de prueba:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  counter-reset: section;  
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.coso {
 
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) " ";
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius:30px;
  color: white;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Using CSS Counters:</h1>
<div class="coso">
<h2>HTML tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>
<h2>JavaScript Tutorial</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Y al implementar la prueba de los contadores en mi proyecto, ocurren algunas cosas.

Este es el código:

```css
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
  color: white;
  background: #8d33ff;;
}

::selection {
  color: white;
  background: #8d33ff;;
}

h6::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) " ";
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius:30px;
  color: white;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#contadores {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}

body {
 font-family: Verdana;
 background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1206/1206290.png");
 width: 100%;
 background-size: 100px 80px;
  counter-reset: section; 
}

/* Redimensión */

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contenido2 {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:center;
}

/* Estructura flex */

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: none;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: none;
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

p {
    background: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.5);
}

a,p, h6 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#contenido2 {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:left;
}

.receta {
 font-size: 25px;
 color: DarkSlateBlue;
 background: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.6);
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.contenido {
 background: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.6);
}

.final {
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.6);
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
</head>

<body>

<div class="flex-container" id="contenido2">

 <div style="flex-grow: 10">
  
  <h1 class="receta"> Preparación </h1>
  
   <div class="contenido" id="contadores" style="text-align: left; font-family: verdana;">
   
      <h6>
        Ponemos en el vaso de la batidora los huevos, la mantequilla, el azúcar, la sal, la leche y batimos       todo.
      </h6> 

    <h6>
        Incorporamos la harina junto con la levadura y batimos todo de nuevo.
      </h6> 
      <h6>
        Dejamos que la mezcla repose unos 20 minutos.
      </h6>
      
      <h6>
        En una plancha o sartén antiadherente con un trocito de mantequilla o margarina engrasamos la 
      superficie.
      </h6>
      
      <h6>
        Vertemos la mezcla en una jarrita y ponemos un poco de la mezcla en la sartén.
      </h6>

      <h6>
        Esperamos hasta que toda la superficie se llene de burbujitas, entonces con una espátula le damos 
      la vuelta; dejamos que se dore por el otro lado, unos segundos y sacamos.
      </h6>
      
      <h6>
        Repetimos la operación hasta que se nos acabe la mezcla. Vamos poniendo las tortitas en un plato una       encima de otra y tapamos con papel aluminio.
      </h6>
  </div> 
   <p class="final"><b> ¡Has terminado! </b></p>
  
 </div>
 
</div>

</body>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</html>
```

No hace caso al `font-size` indicado en el estilo. También quiero que el contador esté a la par de la primera línea, y no en medio.

El final antes estaba centrado, pero al colocar esto se movió. Tiene definido el `text-align: center;` pero no hace caso a eso.

Comment: Podrias mndar una captura de pantalla de como se ve actualmente?

Comment: Se puede ver en el segundo snippet @JonathanOrta

Comment: Creo que el problema principal es que tienes demasiado lío en la organización del código CSS, en el nombrado de los elementos, etc. Hay reglas que se superponen, que redundan, que se dicen y se contradicen. Todo eso tienes que tomarlo en cuenta. Por poner un ejemplo, en CSS un id (que empieza por `#`) tiene prioridad sobre una clase (que empieza por `.`). Dado que los estilos se aplican en cascada, si primero aplicas un estilo sobre una clase y a continuación aplicas sobre un id que usa esa clase, sobre-escribes las reglas sobre ese elemento, perdiendo en rendimiento...

Comment: Le daré unas vueltas al css a ver si puedo arreglar eso, muchas gracias @A.Cedano

Comment: ... eso ocurre en tu código y es en parte debido a que no tienes bien organizados los elementos. Otro problema es la mezcla que haces poniendo estilos *in line*, como aquí por ejemplo: `<div class="contenido" id="contadores" style="text-align: left; font-family: verdana;">` ... Hacer eso va contra el espíritu de CSS. ¿Por qué no aplicas esas reglas desde el CSS? Lo que quiero decir con esto es que **la organización es fundamental** cuando trabajas con CSS. Si no te armas un lío y empiezas a dar palos de ciego y tu código se convierte en un spaghetti.

Comment: !important es para enfatizar algo en css , te suena?

Comment: Sí @Iria pero tengo entendido que no se debe abusar de esa regla, por lo tanto trato de evitarla

Comment: entonces siempre puedes crear otra clase para el caso. Personalmente si usas ids, usa ids, y si usas clases usa clase, pero no mezcles

Comment: @Iria es **importante** evitar en la medida de lo posible el uso de `!important` ([ver aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/90264/29967)).

Comment: es cierto, pero es una de esas cosas que cuando tienes lineas y lineas de codigo enmarañado es probable que no te quede más remedio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo una estructura alternativa para tu **HTML** ya que considero que hacer todo el sistema desde dentro de un `<h6>` además de atentar contra el **SEO**, te da muy poca flexibilidad.

A mi entender cada elemento de *contador + texto* forma parte de una fila con dos columnas (una para el contador y la otra para el texto) por lo que he creado un `.contador` con dentro dos columnas: `.contador-numero` y `.contador-texto`.

Por medio de `display: flex` le damos a `.contador` comportamiento de fila, para que trate a sus hijos como columnas y ya tendríamos solucionada la mayor parte de la problemática.

Para provocar que el texto de `.final` saliese centrado, le he obligado a usar `display: block` en vez de `display: flex` de esa manera la regla `text-align: center` si que puede afectarle.

Los demás cambios que hice son meramente estéticos, como darle a los contadores un aspecto más redondeado y con el número en el centro del círculo.

```css
/****** Nuevas estructura ******************************************/
h1.receta {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contador {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.contador-texto p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  margin: 0px;
}

.contador-numero p {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.contador-numero p:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) " ";
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius:50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  max-width: 45px;
  max-height: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}



/********************************************************************/




::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
  color: white;
  background: #8d33ff;;
}

::selection {
  color: white;
  background: #8d33ff;;
}

#contadores {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}

body {
 font-family: Verdana;
 background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1206/1206290.png");
 width: 100%;
 background-size: 100px 80px;
  counter-reset: section; 
}

/* Redimensión */

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contenido2 {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:center;
}

/* Estructura flex */

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: none;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: none;
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

p {
    background: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.5);
}

a,p, h6 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#contenido2 {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:left;
}

.receta {
 font-size: 25px;
 color: DarkSlateBlue;
 background: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.6);
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.contenido {
 background: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.6);
}

.final {
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.6);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
</head>

<body>

<div class="flex-container" id="contenido2">

 <div style="flex-grow: 10">
  
  <h1 class="receta"> Preparación </h1>
  
   <div class="contenido" id="contadores" style="text-align: left; font-family: verdana;">
   <div class="contador">
        <div class="contador-numero">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="contador-texto">
          <p>Ponemos en el vaso de la batidora los huevos, la mantequilla, el azúcar, la sal, la leche y batimos todo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="contador">
        <div class="contador-numero">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="contador-texto">
          <p>Incorporamos la harina junto con la levadura y batimos todo de nuevo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    <div class="contador">
        <div class="contador-numero">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="contador-texto">
          <p>Dejamos que la mezcla repose unos 20 minutos.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="contador">
        <div class="contador-numero">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="contador-texto">
          <p>En una plancha o sartén antiadherente con un trocito de mantequilla o margarina engrasamos la superficie.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="contador">
        <div class="contador-numero">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="contador-texto">
          <p>Vertemos la mezcla en una jarrita y ponemos un poco de la mezcla en la sartén.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="contador">
        <div class="contador-numero">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="contador-texto">
          <p>Esperamos hasta que toda la superficie se llene de burbujitas, entonces con una espátula le damos la vuelta; dejamos que se dore por el otro lado, unos segundos y sacamos.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="contador">
        <div class="contador-numero">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="contador-texto">
          <p>Repetimos la operación hasta que se nos acabe la mezcla. Vamos poniendo las tortitas en un plato una encima de otra y tapamos con papel aluminio.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div> 
   <p class="final">¡Has terminado!</p>
  
 </div>
 
</div>

</body>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! ¿Habría alguna forma de hacer que el número quede alineado con la primera línea de texto? Probé con `align-items:flex-start` pero sale algo descolocado

Comment: Podrías ajustar el `top` que le di a `.contador-numero p:before` para dejarlo a tu gusto ^^

Answer (score 1):

### Debes ubicar h6::before

En la línea `11` ubique:

```css
h6::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) " ";
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius:30px;
  color: white;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Y reemplace `padding-right: 10px` por `padding: 0 10px`,  elimine `font-size: 20px` y agregue `margin-top: 7px`:

Es decir, dejando esto:

```css
h6::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) " ";
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius:30px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Ubicar también:

```css
a,p, h6 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Y cambie `align-items: center` por `align-items: flex-start`:

```css
a,p, h6 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Eso solucionó el centrar el número, pero aún así el texto se ve a la mitad en vez de el número alineado con la primera línea de texto, y tampoco hace caso al tamaño de letra que le defino

Answer (score 1):

En este ejemplo cuando no cabe en la línea salta a la siguiente empezado desde la misma posción que el before de la sección. Al igual que se hace en https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp

Ajusta el padding o el margin del **h6** según tu interés. Ten en cuenta que si cambias el font-size del **h6** tendrás que modificar también el padding del **h6::before**

```css
.container {
  // background-color: green;
  // color: white;
  counter-reset: section;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 8px auto;
}

h6::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section);
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  background: blue;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h6>Ponemos en el vaso de la batidora los huevos.</h6>
    <h6>Ponemos en el vaso de la batidora los huevos, la mantequilla, el azúcar, la sal, la leche y batimos todo.</h6>
    <h6>Ponemos en el vaso de la batidora los huevos, la mantequilla, el azúcar, la sal, la leche y batimos todo.</h6>
    <h6>Ponemos en el vaso de la batidora los huevos, la mantequilla, el azúcar, la sal, la leche y batimos todo.</h6>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```